# iOS App: Free -> InApp Subscription model

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a question and I wonder if they have had a similar experience.
We are finalizing an application in which we only need  implement InApp Purchase.

My question:
If we send application with free features, during the review process we add buttons and premium features, and then we do an update with the payment features. Will Apple can reject the update?

The idea is to use the review time to end up the premium features and then publish the final version with all features (free and premium).
What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: Your app will need to be reviewed for every update that is pushed. End of story. No skipping an update by pushing an earlier one first.

Comment: But, is there any problem if we convert a free function to a payment function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple would not have a reason to reject your app for adding paid premium features in an update. However, you will have to wait for the first version to release before you can submit an update for Apple to review.

However, converting a free feature to a paid feature seems problematic if people who have been using these features suddenly find themselves locked out after installing your update.